# CodeMirror Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, ios, codemirror, ui-codemirror

So I am using CodeMirror to create an iOS Web App that teaches you how to use basic JavaScript and I only just realized that CodeMirror does not automatically resize to fit the screen of the device and the code doesn't fit on the screen... So I realy need to A. Either Make CodeMirror fit on the screen perfectly. Or B. Have a completly custom syntax highlighting textarea that is completly responsive.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably mean by *fit on the screen perfectly* is the default padding of the body. To remove it:

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Next I would recommend this viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

If you want to change the font size you can do so like this:

```
.CodeMirror {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And if the CodeMirror should be full height:

```
.CodeMirror {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/maxjmB